# Difficulty Using Import-Module function output to properly return a HashTable

Tags: powershell, import

So I wanted to set up a function in an import template, which returns a HashTable. But I'm encountering a weird conversion issue when this happens.
Main Script:

```
    $MigrationConfig = 'Migrate.Default',
$MigrationConfigPath = '.\MigrationConfigs\' + $MigrationConfig + '.psm1';
Import-Module -Name $($MigrationConfigPath);
if (((Get-Command -Module $MigrationConfig -ListImported) | Where-Object Name -eq 'GetSections').Length -ne 1) {throw "Migration Config $MigrationConfig which should be located at $MigrationConfigPath must export a function named 'GetSections'.";}
```

The idea is to feed it a new value in $MigrationConfig (param) to load a new query set. The main script then looks for the function by the name of GetSections, then uses the return of that function, expecting HashTable for ease of use, to run the rest of the script. Here's a sample of the psm file.

```
function GetSections {
    return [HashTable]@{
        'MigrationProc' = [ordered]@{
            '1' = @{<#...#>}
        };
    };
};
```

However, I've been running tests on the setup by manually importing the file and trying to treat the output as a HashTable...

```
foreach($f in ((Get-Command -Module 'Migrate.Default' -ListImported) | Where-Object Name -eq 'GetSections')) {([HashTable]([ScriptBlock]::Create($f.ScriptBlock).Invoke('1'))).Keys}
```

But what I get back is this:

```
Cannot convert the "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]" value of type 
"System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.Management.Automation.PSObject, System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".
```

How can I structure the main script or the import module to treat the function output as a HashTable?

Comment: You are missing curly brackets : Where-Object {Name -eq 'GetSections'}

Comment: This returns a different exception saying that Name is not recognized.

Comment: Should be $_.Name

Comment: Still get the conversion error in the OP.

Comment: @jdweng, `Where-Object Name -eq 'GetSections'` - and even `Where-Object Name -eq GetSections` - is perfectly valid syntax - namely [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax).

Comment: @jdweng, since this is not an isolated incident: Can I suggest abstaining from commenting on PowerShell syntax issues until you're familiar with PowerShell's syntax? Your comments are creating unnecessary distractions.

Comment: @mklement0 : You need curly brackets when there are other pipe commands.  Even if it is  not needed, adding helps isolate what is really wrong.

Comment: @jdweng, your comment is yet another distraction. There's no need to fix a part of the question that isn't broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke your command as follows, which takes advantage of the ability of `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), to invoke commands represented as instances of type [`System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo), as output by [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command):

```
(& (Get-Command -Module Migrate.Default -Name Get-Sections) 1).Keys
```

If there's no concern about *naming conflicts* (i.e. if you expect only *one* installed module to export a command named `Get-Sections`):

```
(Get-Sections 1).Keys
```